# SFTP access to OpsWorks files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp, aws-opsworks

I have multiple apps installed in an AWS OpsWorks stack. In order to troubleshoot an app I would like SFTP access to the files that are otherwise deployed from Git. I don't see where the files are located on the instance, if I access it with SFTP.
Can anybody tell me where to look or what my options are?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the chef logs it might give you the location. For more info:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-debug-log.html